# What's the meaning of preposition 'against' in the sentence?

Tags: prepositions

**I drew a check against my bank balance.**

In dictionary i found its meaning as-"to the account or debt of", but i could understand it clearly, plz someone explain me in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Against" in this context means "lowering the value of" - which is the same in meaning as the one you listed.

A bank balance is the amount of money you have in a bank account. If you draw a check, you are taking money out of that bank account, it is lowering the balance.

Comment: To the account of mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but the meaning you found is intended to describe the first object lowering some value of the second object.